# How to Add Style to Google Earth Balloon

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Can some one let me know How I can add CSS class/Style to Google Earth Ballon which has been created from `createFeatureBalloon()` method?

I already tried this code by adding  `.setAttribute("class", "myStyle");` to ballon object but it seems it is not working here.Can you please let me know is there any way to do this in Google Earth?

```javascript
function showBalloon() {
    var balloon = ge.createFeatureBalloon('div');
    balloon.setFeature(placemark);
    balloon.setAttribute("class", "myStyle");
    balloon.setMaxWidth(600);
    ge.setBalloon(balloon); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ballon with:

```
var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
```

Then you create a variable with the html code and then use:

```
balloon.setContentString(html);
```

You can view https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons?hl=in